# 'I made it' and 'I did it' vs 'I have made it' and 'I have done it'

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Why do English speakers say 'I made it!' and 'I did it!' instead of 'I have made it!' and 'I have done it!' when talking about succeed results of their actions. As far as I know, they should say 'have/has done' when talking about results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you take in account the 'rules' of the language you would have to use the present perfect tense like so:

> - I've done it!
> - I've made it!

Now, I have seen these expressions in the present perfect before and am quite confident that they are also used. However, these expressions are used often as well:

> - I did it!
> - I made it!

The reason for this, I think, is simply that they have become a sort of fixed expressions. Language changes through languages use, and if an expression is used often enough it will become an exception to the rule.

Comment: "Have done" is present perfect, not past perfect ("had done").

Answer (score 1):

I think we have to start from the question... it's not about the results but rather about who actually has done it! Don't be around written rules but the idea! English is a more communicative than grammatical language. So when you say **I did it**, you want to make clear the person who did the action (the subject "I") and it was a fact in the past... in your head you have just that moment you did the action! When you say **I have done it** you emphasize the result, which you want to show that is important to the information! I'm no good in English but I try to get what natives think.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because in modern English there is a growing trend to use past simple instead of present perfect due to simplicity of past simple, even if present perfect is required grammatically.

See the evolution of usage of "I just arrived" vs "I have just arrived":

[image]

pic [source](https://jakubmarian.com/i-just-did-it-vs-i-have-just-done-it-present-perfect-or-past-simple/)

DISCLAIMER: English is not my mother language.